# Revolution R Enterprise with R version 3.2.2 and caret package

Tags: r, revolution-r

I am using Revolution R Enterprise with R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)

when I am trying to installed `library(caret)` I got this error

```
library(caret)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘caret’ was built under R version 3.2.5 
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.2.4 
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
```

please help me
I tried many things and every things but I still have this error

Comment: It maybe helps to (re)install Rcpp package

Comment: install.packages("Rcpp", lib="C:/Program Files/Microsoft/MRO-for-RRE/8.0/R-3.2.2/library")   then trying URL 'http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/Rcpp_0.12.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3224912 bytes (3.1 MB)
downloaded 3.1 MB

package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpoDvTjp\downloaded_packages
> library(Rcpp)
Warning message:
package ‘Rcpp’ was built under R version 3.2.5

Comment: I have installed this package as I showed in above comment but I received this Warning message: package ‘Rcpp’ was built under R version 3.2.5

Comment: Any another suggestion please !1

Answer (score 0):

So, that warning is pretty common with R packages. It is just a disclosure of what version the package was tuned to when it was created. That does not mean the package did not install properly.So there are a few things that I do when this happens (and it happened to me at work today with the sp mapping package).

1. If you are in RStudio, use the tools to update all packages as well updating R itself, save everything in your script, close it up. Restart you entire computer.
2. Reinstall the packages you need with `install.packages("packagename", dependencies= TRUE)`. If a package is dependent on another package, then you will catch it here.
3. Then go back through the console and see all of the dependent package names that installed with your new package and update those with `dependencies=TRUE` as well. It is possible the Rcpp is installed but needs another package to support your target package.
4. I would again properly quit R or RStudio and then reboot the computer again.

I know it seems like overkill, but it has worked miracles for me on many occasions. You need to start all the way at the beginning to make it happen.

Comment: thanks for trying to help,I tried it but unfortunately it does not work for me. Actually I need caret package to measure the performance of my model through using confusionMatrix () function . since I could not to install it,  is there any another method to measure the performance in R ???

Comment: I just had a nightmare with ggplot2 also, it would not work after install. The problem was the Rcpp. And that would not finish installing (after it successfully installed many dependencies). It gave a message saying that the the package could not be moved from the temp folder to the library. I copied that address and went to the temp folder. There was a zip file in there for Rcpp, I clicked on it, 7zip asked where to extract it to, I pointed it to my R/library folder..it unzipped and now everything is working fine.